# Is it Possible to have Multiple lambda functions in single Go binary?

Tags: go, aws-lambda, serverless

I am experimenting with Go on AWS lambda, and i found that each function requires a binary to be uploaded for execution.

My question is that, is it possible to have a single binary that can have  two different `Handler` functions, which can be loaded by two different lambda functions.

for example

```
func Handler(request events.APIGatewayProxyRequest) (events.APIGatewayProxyResponse, error) {
    fmt.Println("Received body in Handler 1: ", request.Body)

    return events.APIGatewayProxyResponse{Body: request.Body, StatusCode: 200}, nil
}
func Handler1(request events.APIGatewayProxyRequest) (events.APIGatewayProxyResponse, error) {
    fmt.Println("Received body in Handler 2: ", request.Body)

    return events.APIGatewayProxyResponse{Body: request.Body, StatusCode: 200}, nil
}

func EndPoint1() {
    lambda.Start(Handler)
}
func EndPoint2() {
    lambda.Start(Handler1)
}
```

and calling the `EndPoints` in `main` in such a way that it registers both the `EndPoints` and the same binary would be uploaded to both the functions `MyFunction1` and `MyFunction2`.

I understand that having two different binary is good because it reduces the load/size of each function.

But this is just an experimentation.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe it is not possible since Lambda console says the handler is the name of the executable file:

> Handler: The executable file name value. For example, "myHandler" would call the main function in the package “main” of the myHandler executable program.

So one single executable file is unable to host two different handlers.

Answer (score 1):

you can do the workaround to have same executable to upload to two different lambda like following

```
func main() {
switch cfg.LambdaCommand {
case "select_lambda_1":
    lambda1handler()
case "select_lambda_2":
    lambda2handler()
```

Answer (score 1):

I've had success by adding an environment variable to the functions in the template.yaml, and making the main() check the variable and call the appropriate handler.